# NPM custom module location

Tags: npm

after running npm install commande it download a node_module folder in the current location 
please I want to change the node_module location
can specify a parameter to npm start for the module location?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

npm won't let you change the node_modules directory for local packages.

Check these links for some past discussion - unfortunately the FAQ links given don't work any more:

https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/3597#issuecomment-20752876
https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/775#issuecomment-1389398

You can change the location for global `-g` installed packages using the [prefix](https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/config#prefix) config setting:

```
npm config set prefix /your/path
```

This will install global packages in `/your/path/node_modules`